# How can I partition a usb flashdrive in Win7

Tags: usb-drive

I want to be able to create a Ubuntu boot disk using a USB flash drive. I also want to be able to create a second partition for my data on the same drive. How can I create the partition in Win7?
The flash drive is 8Gb in size.
The idea is to be able to run a self-contained Ubuntu from the flash drive with Ubuntu opsys on the first partition and any data that I might create to be saved to the second partition.

Comment: Since this question is not about installing Ubuntu on a flash drive, but rather about *partitioning* a flash drive, it is off-topic here.  I suggest you ask over on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).  Thanks!

Comment: @Seth The question is asking how to create an Ubuntu system alongside a data partition, on a USB flash drive. That seems on-topic to me. Why would partitioning in Windows *to create an Ubuntu system* be off-topic, when burning an ISO image or writing a USB flash drive in Windows are on-topic when their aim is to create an Ubuntu system? Remember, some people have just one flash drive, and their computers might not have optical drives (e.g., netbooks). They cannot use an Ubuntu live system to do the partitioning--they'll have to do it in Windows.

Comment: @TimWalls Do you want files saved in the Ubuntu system to persist across reboots (being tracked in the storage partition), and configuration changes to be saved in the Ubuntu system? Or do you just want a live USB system with a second partition that can be used for storage? Do you want the second partition to be accessible in Windows, or does it only need to be accessible in Ubuntu. Depending on your answers to these questions, this can probably be answered or closed as a duplicate of another question.

Comment: I want the files and applications installed to the USB flash drive Ubuntu to persist across reboots. I followed some instructions to create such a drive and the Universal Installer has an option to create a persistent area but no applications remained on the drive following a reboot. I have no previous knowledge of Ubuntu use so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't create two or more partitions on one single USB, however if you use unetbootin to install the Ubuntu image, there should be a persistance option, allowing you to store things in that persistance partition. Henceforth if you boot the live USB again you won't lose your data.

Comment: A USB flash drive has all the capabilities of any external hard drive. It's quite easy to create multiple partitions--both Windows and Ubuntu are perfectly capable of this. Depending on the OP's specific needs (I've commented), a persistent area created by UNetbootin might be the best way, or a separately created partition (especially if Windows needs to access the data there) might be the best.